# Laravel - Aggregate result not giving correct result

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I expect to have a result show in the diagram:

[image: incorrect result]

But I got the result below:

[image: wrong result]

The:

1. Total Active users for each row is 0, which is not correct
2. Total Inactive users for each row is 0, which is not correct
3. Total users for each row is 44 and is thesame for all, which is not correct

See my code below:

```
        $subscribers= Cloudsubscriptions::join("services","cloudsubscriptions.service_name","=","services.name")
        ->join("service_type","services.service_type","=","service_type.id")
        ->select("cloudsubscriptions.service_name"
                ,"service_type.name as service_type"
                ,DB::raw("(SELECT count(cloudsubscriptions.id) FROM cloudsubscriptions WHERE('cloudsubscriptions.is_subscribe' = 1)) as total_active_users")
                ,DB::raw("(SELECT count(cloudsubscriptions.id) FROM cloudsubscriptions WHERE('cloudsubscriptions.is_subscribe' = 0)) as total_inactive_users")
                ,DB::raw("(SELECT count(cloudsubscriptions.id) FROM cloudsubscriptions) as total_users"))
        ->groupBy("cloudsubscriptions.service_name")
    ->get();
```

Where have I got it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query.

```
$subscribers= DB::table('cloudsubscriptions')
    ->join("services","cloudsubscriptions.service_name","=","services.name")
    ->join("service_type","services.service_type","=","service_type.id")
    ->select("cloudsubscriptions.service_name"
            ,"service_type.name as service_type"
            ,DB::raw("(SELECT count(*) FROM cloudsubscriptions WHERE is_subscribe = 1 AND services.name = cloudsubscriptions.service_name) as total_active_users")
            ,DB::raw("(SELECT count(*) FROM cloudsubscriptions WHERE is_subscribe = 0 AND services.name = cloudsubscriptions.service_name) as total_inactive_users")
            ,DB::raw("(SELECT count(*) FROM cloudsubscriptions WHERE services.name = cloudsubscriptions.service_name) as total_users"))
    ->groupBy("cloudsubscriptions.service_name")
->get();
```

This is a very bad practice from my point of view. You have eloquent relation from laravel. Eloquent relation will make your work easier.

Comment: When I did as you said, the total active users equals to total inactive users, only total users is correct. It should be: total users = total active users + total inactive users.   See the updated diagram for the wrong result

Comment: I made database like you, and tested the query to that. wait give me some moment, I will look it again.
If you tell me, which values show incorrect, then it helps me to find out the problem.

Comment: I cannot find out anything. It shows everything ok in my point. here is the image link. https://imgur.com/a/fRMQCQr
If you tell me, which value shows there, active or inactive?

Comment: Am very sorry. You are correct. I wrongly type total_active twice instead of total_active   total_inactive.  Thanks